# Python Crash Course Chapter 17- The Hacker News API

Tags: python, api, python-requests

```
import requests
from operator import itemgetter

#make an API call and store the response
url = 'https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/9884165.json'
r = requests.get(url)
print('Status code:' , r.status_code)

#process info about each submission
submission_ids = r.json()
submission_dicts = []
for submission_id in submission_ids:
    #make separate API call for each submission
    url = ("https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/" 
           + str(submission_id)+ '.json')
submission_r = requests.get(url)
print(submission_r.status_code)
response_dict = submission_r.json()
submission_dict = {'title' : response_dict['title'],
                   "link" : 'https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item?id='
                   + str(submission_id) + '.json',
                   'comments': response_dict.get('descendants', 0),
                   }
submission_dicts.append(submission_dict)

submission_dicts = sorted(submission_dicts, key=itemgetter('comments'),
                          reverse=True)

for submission_dict in submission_dicts:
    print("\nTitle:", submission_dict['title'])
    print("Discussion link:", submission_dict['link'])
    print("Comments:", submission_dict['comments'])
```

when i try to run my code, i get an error saying that 'NoneType' object is not callable

```
submission_dict = {'title' : response_dict['title'],
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

the expected output should be the title of the current top articles in Hacker News along with the number of comments and link of the article.
can someone tell me what part of my code went wrong and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a simple error I hope.

```
#process info about each submission
submission_ids = r.json()
print( type( submission_ids ))
```

--> dict - which means submission_id in the following for loop is a key, you want the value. Replace submission_id --> submission_ids[submission_id] like so.

```
for submission_id in submission_ids:
    
    #make separate API call for each submission
    url = ("https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/" 
           + str(submission_ids[submission_id])+ '.json')
```

Comment: thank you for this solution. i was able to find out what was wrong with my code especially with the for block. submission_ids turned out to be a dictionary. the key i was looking for was 'id' but nevertheless this answer has been really helpful